# Make sent items appear in Outlook 2010 conversation without exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Hi I just installed outlook 2010, and saw this conversation feature.
However my sent mails does not appear in the conversation.
How do I make it appear there?

PS: I'm not using exchange. Is there a way to do this without exchange?

EDIT: There's something Weird happening. I'm testing this and it appears to work only sometimes. And When I Try this at the other company's computer that uses Exchange, but don't have exchange Cached mode enabled this doesn't work. And the option Show messages from other folders is not even there.

Comment: I have the same problem with windows live mail, how to view sent mail in conversation inbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You turn on Conversation View by going to the View Ribbon and tiking the box "Show as Conversations" for the folder you want to see them in (eg Inbox, or all folders).
Below that is a button for Conversation settings, the first option allows you to include mesages from other folders and is on by default, but make sure this is still ticked.

When you click on the conversation header, it will only expand the conversation to show email messages *from the current folder* which are *not redundant*.

If you want to see all, including redundant messages or ones from another folder such as Sent items, you need to explicitly expand it fully using the little white arrow at the left of the header (which then turns black and points down to the right).

Exchange is not required to do this.

Comment: I'm testing this and it appears to work only sometimes. And When I Try this at the other company's computer that uses Exchange, but don't have exchange Cached mode enabled this doesn't work. And the option Show messages from other folders is not even there.

Comment: This could be an indexing problem. Click in the search box and have a look on the Search ribbon which appears for Search tools > Indexing status and check that everything is indexed. Also Search tools > search options leads to various options and button to check what is being indexed, where you can also change it if it is not correct.

Comment: It seems to be necessary to enable Always Expand Conversations, otherwise sent items aren't shown, even with Show Messages From Other Folders enabled.

Comment: Clicking the little triangle did work for me, but selecting 'Always Expand Conversations' is less confusing.

Comment: Both "Show as Conversations" and "Show messages from other folders" options are checked but still no sign of my sent items in the conversation, also when clicking on the little white arrow. I am using Outlook 2016.